# EF Code First not lazy loading just on property after data import

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm currently using EF version 4.3.1 with SQL 2008 R2

When I run the application with data generated by the application, everything works fine, but as soon as I import data, then only one of the properties does not want to lazy load.

Here is the Order class I'm using:

```
[DisplayName("Orders")]
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    [DisplayName("Order Number")]
    public virtual string OrderNumber { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Order name cannot be more than 30 characters.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Order Status")]
    public virtual OrderStatus OrderStatus { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public Byte[] TimeStamp { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Customer")]
    [Required()]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Order Lines")]
    public virtual ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}
```

When loop through all the orders:

```
foreach (var order in orders)
        {
            returnValue.Add(new FriendlyOrder()
            {
                Customer = order.Customer.Name,
                Name = order.Name,
                OrderNumber = order.OrderNumber,
                OrderStatus = order.OrderStatus.Status
            });
        }
```

The Order status will lazy load, but not the Customer, Customer will be null.  When I run the SQL query manually, then the relationship is there, so it is not related to bad data.

Here is the Customer entity:

```
[DisplayName("Customers")]
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    [DisplayName("Customer Code")]
    public string CustomerCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public Byte[] TimeStamp { get; set; }

}
```

Here is the query for orders:

```
return (from tbl in db.Orders orderby tbl.OrderNumber select tbl).ToList();
```

If I manually include the .Include("Customer") to the above query, then it will load the Customer property, but if I have both properties set to virtual, I shouldn't need to do this?  Also, it works fine on data generated by the application, but data imported does not work unless I add the .Include to the query?

Comment: what if you make all properties of customer class virtual ? sometimes i have seen that even if one property is non virtual EF would not be able generate a proxy type

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried that and it made no difference.  It also doesn't explain why the other property (Order Status) is being lazy loaded...

Comment: By import you mean a mechanism that adds records to the database besides the application, right?

Answer (score 3):

Writing **virtual** for lazy fields allow EF to derive from class you written and overload that fields with lazy functionality. So, lazyloading can only work on object of EF internal type, which you are actually working with most of the time, and there is no obvious way to get object of that type except letting EF to create it.

As for me, it seems that the only way to get the result you want is:

1. Add exported object to appropriate dataset
2. commit changes
3. remove object from tracking
4. query for object so it will be generated by EF from scratch.

Comment: So when you say "Add exported object to appropriate dataset", are you referring to the .Include method, i.e. db.Orders.Include("Customer")?

Comment: that was a solution for objects created in your code or recieved from some 3rd party code.

Comment: @Halceyon but it led me to some futher thinking and... Did you enables MultipleResultSet? If not - add this "MultipleActiveResultSets=True" to your connection string. It should help.